# Доступ к связанной таблице без доп. запроса

Tags: python, django

Есть три модели (диалог, сообщения и пользователи):

```
class Dialog(models.Model):

    Partakers = models.ManyToManyField(Profile, related_name='dialogs', through="Dialog_Partakers")


class Messages(models.Model):
    Sender = models.ForeignKey(Profile)
    Time = models.DateTimeField(default=present_time)                            
    Content = models.TextField()
    Target = models.ForeignKey(Dialog, related_name='messages', related_query_name="messages")
```

`Profile` - обычная расширенная модель джанговского пользователя.

И мне нужно через Диалоги получить содержимое сообщения и имя его отправителя. С получением тела сообщения проблем уже не возникает: решил через `subquery`. Но вот с его отправителем проблема:

```
lastMessageSender = Subquery(Message.objects.filter(Target=OuterRef('id')).order_by('-id').values('Sender')[:1])
qs = qs.annotate(Sender=lastMessageSender).annotate(sender_name=lastMessageSender__username)
```

Получаю `global name 'lastMessageSender__username' is not defined`.

Пробовал так же через prefetch_related:

```
qs = qs.prefetch_related(Prefetch('messages', queryset=Message.objects.select_related('Target')))
```

И в шаблоне:

```
{{ dialog.messages.last.username }}
```

Ошибок не возникает, но в django toolbar вижу 4 лишних запроса.

Как грамотно получить имя отправителя сообщения без доп запроса?